# Cylinder From View UV unwrap stopped working (v2.49b)

Tags: uv

So I have been using Cylinder from view unwrap for awhile with no problems and the other day it sudden;y stopped working. Instead of laying out the UV in a parallelogram  rectangle, it stacks all of the edges in a line more or less and casts them somewhere way off the texture map. Anyone have any idea what's going on? Is there any particular script or other file I should check to see if it's corrupt or something? I'd re-install Blender but because the /Blender/.Blend folder has all my .Blend files and they are completely invisible to me outside of Blender 2.49b I'm paranoid I'm going to lose them of I reinstall.

Comment: I think the first question is: Is there a particular reason you haven't upgraded to 2.78?

Comment: @Ray Mairlot he could be needing some old addon that have never been ported to 2.5x+ maybe... just guessing of course. Or, very old or basic hardware (although all versions are still available on the blender website... he could try the most recent that works on his rig)

Comment: @Icecreamassassin if you are willing to reinstall, couldn't it be just safe to take a backup copy of that folder, and restore your files from there, if something fails?

Comment: Now this right here is a gem of a question, didn't expect to see anyone actively using Blender 2.49 in 2017 :). Saving work files inside the installation folder is of course very bad practice and organization policy, and a sure way to get your data unintentionally erased by mistake or installation procedures.

Comment: Yeah I use 2.49b because until very recently the NIFscripts tools for NIFSkope and Skyrim had not been updated. I think updated scripts just came out but I haven't looked into it yet. This clearly has something to do with an object property somewhere I am missing. I reset Blender to factory settings and loaded up my model without the UI so it would be fresh and that doesn't help.